# Modifying custom elements' style in shadow root

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am attempting to modify the styles of two custom HTML elements, "output-screen" and "custom-calculator" using shadow DOM.

When I try to do so by attaching a shadow DOM as shown below, the styles are not applied. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arqc6j49/4/)

```
<custom-calculator id="calculator">
  <output-screen></output-screen>
</custom-calculator>

<script>
var o = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
    var oElement = document.registerElement('output-screen', {
        prototype: o
    });

var c = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
var cElement = document.registerElement('custom-calculator', {
  prototype: c
});

var calc = document.querySelector('#calculator')
calc.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
calc.shadowRoot;
calc.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
<style>
output-screen{
display:inline-block;
background-color:orange;
width:50%;
height:100vh;
}
custom-calculator {
display:inline-block;
background-color:grey;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
`;
</script>
```

Comment: @Supersharp Would v1 be: customElements.define('custom-calculator', class extends HTMLElement {
}) ?

Comment: yes it is: look at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements also you should create the Shadow within the custom element constructor()

Comment: I tried something like this: `customElements.define('custom-calculator', class extends HTMLElement {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.innerHTML = [style from before here];}})`from the documentation to no avail. What am I missing here?

Comment: don't forget to create the Shadow root: `this.attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML=...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to style the element that hosts the Shadow DOM, here `<custom-calculator>`, you must use de [`:host`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#host) pseudo-class (instead of `custom-calculator` which is unknown inside the Shadow DOM).

```
:host {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:grey;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Because the Shadow DOM will replace/recover the normal DOM tree (here `<output-screen>`), you'll have to use [`<slot>`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#composition_slot) to insert/reveal it in the Shadow DOM.

```
calc.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    ...
  </style>
  <slot></slot>`
```

Then, in order to style what is revealed by/in the `<slot>` element, you mus use the [`::slotted()`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#stylinglightdom) pseudo-element:

```
::slotted( output-screen ){
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:orange;
  width:50%;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Live example:

```js
var calc = document.querySelector('#calculator')
calc.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
calc.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    :host {
      display:inline-block;
      background-color:grey;
      width:100%;
      height:100vh;
      vertical-align:top;
    }

    ::slotted( output-screen ){
      display:inline-block;
      background-color:orange;
      width:50%;
      height:100vh;
    }
  </style>
  <slot></slot>`;
```

```html
<custom-calculator id="calculator">
  <output-screen></output-screen>
</custom-calculator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntax when working with [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements) as it tends to make things clearer.

Here is a step by step working adaptation from the code you provide :

**1. String templates :** 
The first thing you need to do is to define the templates that you will use.

```
const string_templates = {
    "custom-calculator": `<style>
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: grey;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
    </style>
    <slot></slot>`, // !! slot !!
    "output-screen": `<style>
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: orange;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>`
};
```

Here we declare an associative array which stores entries under the `"key":'value'` format. We have two entries whose keys are `"custom-calculator"` and `"output-screen"` each one store as a string value the template that is associated with it.

As the `<custom-calculator>` *element* will receive other `HTMLElement` inside its html tags **we need to add a** `<slot>` *element* **in its template**. The position of this `<slot>` *element* in the *template* defines where the html code  provided inside the `<custom-selector>` *tags* will be *rendered* in that *element*.

**2. Create definitive templates from string templates :** 
Those *templates* will be used when creating new *custom elements* instances.

```
const calc_template = document.createElement('template'); // creates a new <template> element
calc_template.innerHTML = string_templates["custom-calculator"]; // parse the string template only one time

const out_template = document.createElement('template');
out_template.innerHTML = string_templates["output-screen"];
```

Here we define two constants `calc_template` and `out_template` each one is initialized with a new empty `<template>` *element* before adding the associated string template as their `innerHTML` *value*.

Doing this outside of the class allow to parse each template only one time at file runtime.

**3. Classes "CustomCalculator" & "OutputScreen" :** 
The classes used here are pretty simple as they simply consist of a constructor that perform the following actions :

- Calls [super()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) this is **mandatory** prior to the use of `this` because the class is *derived* (extends another class) otherwise there will be a reference error.
- Attach a *shadowRoot* whith a *shadow DOM* to the *element* using [Element.attachShadow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow)
- *Clone* the *content* of the associated *template* and append it as a *child* of the *element*'s *shadow DOM* with [Element.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

**- CustomCalculator class :**

```
// Class for the <custom-calculator> customElement
class CustomCalculator extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super(); // always call super() first
        this.shadow = this.attachShadow( { mode:'open'} ); // attach a shadowRoot to the element
        // clone a template content and add the clone as a shadow DOM child (no <template> tags)
        this.shadow.appendChild( calc_template.content.cloneNode(true) ); 
    } 
} //
```

**Note:** If you want to retrieve the `<output-screen>` *element* from inside the `CustomCalculator` *class* you will have to use `this.querySelector()` instead of `this.shadow.querySelector()`, as the *html content* provided to a *custom element* through a `<slot>` is not part of the *shadow DOM* of this *element* but is instead located inside its *light DOM*. (use page inspector to check that)

**- OutputScreen class :**

```
// Class for the <output-screen> customElement
class OutputScreen extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.shadow = this.attachShadow( {mode:'open'} );
        this.shadow.appendChild( out_template.content.cloneNode(true) );
    } 
} //
```

**4. Register the custom elements :** 
When the *templates* and the *classes* used for the *custom elements* are defined we can *register* them using [customElements.define()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define).

**Note:** once a *custom element* **tag** has been defined in a page it could not be used again with another *class*, so if you want to use two *custom elements* that have the same **tag** you will have to change one of them.

```
customElements.define( 'custom-calculator', CustomCalculator ); // register the <custom-calculator> customElement
customElements.define( 'output-screen', OutputScreen ); // register the <output-screen> customElement
```

Don't forget the "**s**" at the end of the first part of the instruction it is a source of error.

### **Utilization :**

The easiest way is to replace the *content* of your `<script>` *tag* with the code highlighted above using the same order.

If you choose to save this code in a js file **i.e. custom_calculator.js**,  you could import it in your page using this line of *html* :

```
<script type="module" src="./PATH/custom_calculator.js"></script>
```

At this point every time you put the following *html code* in your page you should have the correct *custom elements* instantiated with their *default style*.

```
<custom-calculator>
    <output-screen></output-screen>
</custom-calculator>
```

### **Modify the default style of a custom element :**

I can now answer the title question, but before going into more details I will add some context for when this use case will be needed.

> Let's say you worked on a project in which you developped some *custom
> elements*. Now working on a new project you want to use some of the
> *custom elements* you have already created but their *default style* do not match the *style* used in the new project.

What can be done in order to make a custom element more re usable in regard of its styling ?

You could add a [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) method to the body of the custom element class code below :

```
class CustomCalculator extends HTMLElement {
    constructor( ) { }
    
    static setNewStyle( css_style ) { 
        let new_style = document.createElement('style'); // create a new <style> element
        new_style.textContent = css_style; // set the textContent of the new <style> element as the provided style
        calc_template.content.appendChild( new_style ); // insert the new <style> element at the end of the template content    
    } 

} //

export { CustomCalculator }; // needed to call static methods from other files
```

The *provided argument* `css_style` is a `string` in which you can define the *css rules* you want to apply on the *custom element*. The function will then create a new `<style>` *element* that receive the *provided* `css_style` as *textContent* before adding it as the last child of the definitive template content.

We also need to [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) the *class* of the *custom element* to be able to use the *static methods* from other files.

**Note:** *definitive template* refers to the *template* that is used to instantiate a *custom element* from its *class constructor*.

**How to use :** 
As a static method the `setNewStyle()` method cannot be called from the body of the class or any of its instances. It is used like this: `CustomCalculator.setNewStyle( css_style );`

**Example:** 
For this example the only JavaScript file directly imported in the page is an index.js file. It is imported using the following *html line* : `<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>`

We [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) the *custom element* in **index.js** as follow :

```
import { CustomCalculator } from './PATH/custom_calculator.js';

CustomCalculator.setNewStyle(`
    :host {
        background-color: black;
    }
`); // when instantiated <custom-calculator> elements will now have a black background.
```

On the 1st line we import the *custom element **class***, with the 2nd instruction we call the *static method* `setNewStyle( css_style )` of the *imported class* providing to it a `string` *argument* which redefines the *background-color* on the *custom element* to *black* using a `:host` selector.